# Horizontal list: inline-block vs flex

Tags: css, flexbox

[image: horizontal list screenshot]

Given a horizontal list, what is the practical difference between:

- Normal flow, with all the elements being `display: inline-block`.

and

- List root is `display:flex; flex-flow: wrap;`.

I have tested it on different sizes and haven't noticed any differences, but perhaps there are some more subtle implications, especially how the child elements resize?

Comment: look at this link may help you to understand.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-inline-flex-and-inline-block-in-css/#:~:text=There%20is%20only%20one%20main,specific%20space%20in%20normal%20form.

Answer (score 3):

`display:flex;` provides some more options concerning the alignment of the items both horizontally and vertically, and also concerning the adaption of their size: shrinking or growing in the flex-direction and aligning their size in the cross-axis direction. `inline-block`s simply line up horizontally, keeping their original width and height, and align vertically according to their `vertical-align` parameter setting.

Answer (score 0):

By setting display to inline-block each child get margin-right of 4px by default and default alignment would be by content. but after changing defaults they can be similar, i think you should decide by how you want to change the component in different situations, like in mobile or if you want to change it a little to use somewhere else.
I personally recommend using flexbox, because its easier to maintain.